# how to get quarter offset when a quarter number and year is passed?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Below is the function which returns year and quarter when an offset is passed.

```
function getQuarterStrings(id) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(1);
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - id * 3);
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var quarter = Math.ceil(month / 3);
  return ("Q" + quarter + ", " + year);
}
```

How do I create a new function with two parameters quarter and year and return the offset. For example,current quarter is 0 and when I pass Q2 and 2018 it should return 4.

Comment: you are currently have 1 parameter in your function, but in your question you specify year and quarter. Can you clarify?

Comment: @charlietfl To your question of why Q2 2018 is 4, I assume the answer is that Q2 starts in April (month 4). But now that I look more at the code sample where OP is dividing the month by 3, it seems like my assumption is incorrect

Comment: @ControlAltDel I want to write a new function passing two parameters to implement that functionality. Could you please help Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If your question is: How do I create a new function with two parameters, like you say, please edit your question to reflect that this is what want

Comment: @charlietfl For example current quarter is 0, previous quarter(Q1,2019) is 1, Q4 2018 is 2, Q3 2018 is 3 and Q2 2018 is 4.

Comment: @ControlAltDel updated it, Thanks !!